# How to get HAproxy to return next db server's ip address?

Tags: mysql, php, haproxy

I'd like to use HAproxy for checking if my db servers are online, without actually routing the requests through the HAproxy box. Is there any way I can connect to HAproxy and have it return a DB host IP address?

for example: from webserver #1 I connect to HAproxy on port 3306. HAproxy listens on 3306 and echos DB Host #1 from a list of db hosts(round robin). Then from webserver#1 I connect directly to DB host #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with vanilla haproxy, but I had the same problem and patched haproxy to add exactly this functionality. It may be included in haproxy itself at some point (the author was positive about it, but requested some changes I did not get around to yet).

If you're interested, I'll share this patch. But please ask yourself whether you really need it. Why is "normal" loadbalancing not good enough, maybe with direct server return to make return traffic bypass the loadbalancer. Running a stable, supported, product may be more desirable than having the *exact* functionality you want (which afaik doesn't exist in any open source loadbalancer, and not even in the closed source ones I looked at).

Comment: Thanks.  Is your patch online anywhere?  It might be sufficient for me to bypass the load balancer on the way back.  I haven't found a way to do this.  Any hints for that?

Comment: Reading the documentation again, looks like haproxy doesn't support this, you may want to look at lvs (I looked at quite a few loadbalancers before deciding to hack on haproxy and apparently had this detail mixed up in my memory). I've put the patches [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/seveas/5391216) for you.